# cohomology of finite dimensional grassmannians

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, characteristic-classes

What is the cohomology algebra of finite dimensional grassmannian

$$
H^*(G_k(\mathbb{R}^N);\mathbb{Z}_2)?
$$

$$
H^*(G_k(\mathbb{C}^N);\mathbb{Z}_p)?
$$

$$
H^*(G_k(\mathbb{H}^N);\mathbb{Z}_p)?
$$

I have obtained the infinite version

$$
H^*(G_k(\mathbb{R}^\infty);\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2[w_1,\cdots,w_k],
$$
$p$ prime,
$$
H^*(G_k(\mathbb{C}^\infty);\mathbb{Z}_p)=\mathbb{Z}_p[c_1,\cdots,c_k],
$$
$p\geq 3$ prime,
$$
H^*(G_k(\mathbb{H}^\infty);\mathbb{Z}_p)=\mathbb{Z}_p[p_1,\cdots,p_k].
$$